# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for a class in external JAR

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jar, m2eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I have a maven project in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. 
When running Tomcat, I'm getting an error for a class that *I can see that I have included*.

My question is - **do I have to add these JARs to an additional place because of Tomcat Apache?**

Error:

> SEVERE: Servlet /Resource threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.odata4j.jersey.producer.resources.ODataApplication
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.classForNameWithException(ReflectionHelper.java:240)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.classForNameWithException(ReflectionHelper.java:220)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:711)

And here is the class in my Library:

[image]

UPDATE: 
My Web Deployment Assembly looks like:
[image]

Comment: Is the library being included in the .war file you are deploying?

Comment: I'm currently just testing it on a Tomcat server - I don't need a .war file until I want to deploy, right?

Comment: How are you deploying it to the tomcat server?

Comment: IE, how are you currently getting it to run?

Comment: I right click on the file (in src/main/java) and select "Run As > Run on Server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is due to the fact that tomcat is looking at the wrong directory.  It is currently most likely pointed at your src/main/webapp directory of your project.  This does not jive with how maven works.  Maven downloads the dependencies, but will only include them in the target build.  You need to have the tomcat server look at  target/myapp-0.0.1, or build to a war and deploy that way.  The easiest solution as of now, would be for you to use the tomcat plugin.  After setting it up, you can use an imbedded server, and just use the following command 'mvn tomcat:run'.

[Maven Tomcat Plugin Docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html#Running%20a%20WAR%20project)

UPDATE:

I looked at the properties settings, and you should actually be able to edit the "Web Deployment Assembly" settings for your project (under project properties).  Check screenshot for how I have mine setup.  Notice how Maven Dependencies is mapped.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCIT1.jpg

Comment: Aglassman, thanks so much for the response (and the update which looks much easier!) Just a quick question: when you said to notice how Maven Dependencies is mapped - is that what I need to map? I think it already is...see update above.

Comment: Well it looks like it is mapped correctly.  The next thing I'd check is what you have that dependencies scope set to in your pom.xml for that particular jar.  If it is set to compile or test, that could be causing the issue (set it to provided).  If that doesn't help, I'm not sure I'd know what to try next.

Comment: You're right - I needed a dependency in my pom.xml. What is weird, however, is that I couldn't add odata4j-jersey. What resolved the error was adding odata4j-examples dependency!

Comment: That is odd.  I'd do a search on http://search.maven.org/  to see if you can find the actual dependency in the maven central repo.